# Detect browsers that AREN'T mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I'm using the javascript from http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ to see check if a browser is mobile and then use a different version of my website.

However I'd also ideally like the site to revert to desktop if a browser *isn't* one of the mobile ones.

I don't wanna post the whole thing because it's quite long but the function goes like this:

`(function(a,b){if(/...'http://detectmobilebrowser.com/mobile');`

So basically, I want 'if' to instead have a role of 'if not'. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: This is called **user-agent sniffing**, it's easily spoofed, and it is not recommended to be used. If you're doing this for the sake of responsive design, I highly suggest you learn how to use **media queries**.

Comment: I want specifically mobile devices to have a different experience rather just lower resolution ones though. Both versions will still be responsive so if users spoof it will still be okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouts out to @JennaSloan in the javascript chat - the answer is to use the following:

```
if(!( or if(false==(
```